# ApexCharts YaxisBorder zindex (move yaxisborder behind marker)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, apexcharts

[image: ApexCharts Yaxis > axisBorder zindex]

Trying to keep yaxis border behind maker, but does'nt seem to be working please help

CodeSandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/apexcharts-forked-znw38y?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot do this (yet) with simple configuration. However, ApexCharts is based on SVG, which means that you can manipulate the DOM to do what you want...

The problem here is linked to the fact that order matters. By default, the `<g>` element with class `.apexcharts-inner` (which contains many things, including markers) is placed before the `<g>` element with class `.apexcharts-yaxis`. Consequently, the axis appears on top of your markers. But we can change the order thanks to JavaScript. A [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is useful to watch for changes in the DOM (because, if you resize the chart, the SVG structure will change). I have used this technique several times. **Be aware, though, that it is quite experimental. It is not in the official documentation.**

So... We first need the following function which moves `.apexcharts-yaxis` before `.apexcharts-inner`:

```js
function reorderSvg() {
  var inner = document.querySelector('.apexcharts-inner'),
      yaxis = document.querySelector('.apexcharts-yaxis');
  
  inner.before(yaxis);
}
```

We also put our `MutationObserver` in the function related to the [`mounted` event](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/#mounted):

```js
chart: {
  // ...
  events: {
    mounted: function () {
      var settings = { childList: true },
          observer = new MutationObserver(reorderSvg);

      reorderSvg();
      observer.observe(document.querySelector('#app'), settings);
    },
    // ...
  }
},
```

Here is your code with these little additions:

```js
// ====================== HERE =========================
function reorderSvg() {
  var inner = document.querySelector(".apexcharts-inner"),
      yaxis = document.querySelector(".apexcharts-yaxis");
  
  inner.before(yaxis);
}
// ==================================================

var options = {
  chart: {
    fontFamily: "Lato",
    height: 400,
    type: "area",
    stacked: true,
    events: {
      // ====================== THERE =========================
      mounted: function () {
        var settings = { childList: true },
            observer = new MutationObserver(reorderSvg);

        reorderSvg();
        observer.observe(document.querySelector("#app"), settings);
      },
      // ==================================================
      selection: function (chart, e) {
        console.log(new Date(e.xaxis.min));
      }
    }
  },
  colors: ["#5D62B5", "#29C3BE", "#F2726F"],
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  stroke: {
    curve: "smooth"
  },
  marker: {
    show: true
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "South",
      data: generateDayWiseTimeSeries(
        new Date("11 Feb 2017 GMT").getTime(),
        20,
        {
          min: 10,
          max: 60
        }
      )
    },
    {
      name: "North",
      data: generateDayWiseTimeSeries(
        new Date("11 Feb 2017 GMT").getTime(),
        20,
        {
          min: 10,
          max: 20
        }
      )
    },

    {
      name: "Central",
      data: generateDayWiseTimeSeries(
        new Date("11 Feb 2017 GMT").getTime(),
        20,
        {
          min: 10,
          max: 15
        }
      )
    }
  ],
  fill: {
    type: "gradient",
    gradient: {
      opacityFrom: 0.6,
      opacityTo: 0.8
    }
  },
  legend: {
    position: "top",
    horizontalAlign: "left"
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: "datetime"
  },
  grid: {
    show: true,
    yaxis: {
      lines: {
        show: false
      }
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    show: true,
    axisBorder: { show: true, opacityFrom: 1, opacityTo: 1 },
    crosshairs: {
      show: true,
      position: "back",
      stroke: {
        color: "#b6b6b6",
        width: 1,
        dashArray: 0
      }
    }
  },

  markers: {
    size: 4,
    strokeColors: ["#EC3C07", "#04B96F", "#1881D0"],
    strokeWidth: 1,
    offsetX: 1,
    hover: {
      size: 5
    },
    shape: "circle"
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#app"), options);

chart.render();

/*
  // this function will generate output in this format
  // data = [
      [timestamp, 23],
      [timestamp, 33],
      [timestamp, 12]
      ...
  ]
  */
function generateDayWiseTimeSeries(baseval, count, yrange) {
  var i = 0;
  var series = [];
  while (i < count) {
    var x = baseval;
    var y =
      Math.floor(Math.random() * (yrange.max - yrange.min + 1)) + yrange.min;

    series.push([x, y]);
    baseval += 86400000;
    i++;
  }
  return series;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```